# What is the overhead of using java.util.List for a single element list?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have an in-memory key-value store (probably up to 1GB in size), where map `String` to a `String`.
So far it's been implemented as `Map<String, String>`.

However, there's is a rare case in which I'll need to map to a list of Strings, so I'll need to change that to `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Since this is not a common case (Probably less than %1), I'm debating wether to separate these use cases into two different maps.

Does anyone knows what overhead (memory footprint and CPU) I should expect for having all lists in the map with only one element, vs directly having `String` objects?

Thanks!

Comment: Measure it. Decide whether it's a cost you can bare. I would create my own `Class` that could be either and for example implemented `Iterable`.

Comment: Java is a language, you probably want to know the overhead when used with a certain known compiler or interpreter (or a hybrid of both, as is the case with Oracle JVM). The term "overhead" does not really apply to source code, no matter the language. That's like asking "How fast is this sentence written here?". As for the implied meaning of your question -- I agree with @BoristheSpider -- you need to *measure* in order to *know*, otherwise known as "profiling".

Comment: The cost of a hash miss is pretty low.   You could have a separate map for multiple entries and check that map first.

Comment: Can you ask yourself how important is performance (when accessing this data structure). I would say that 99% cases it's better to bet on readable code then performing code. So my suggestion is to use the MulitMap implementation from Guava. https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html. Then to mess around with 2 data-structures to represent a single concept.

Comment: However to answer your question. As using `Map<String, List<String>>` create a additional level of indirection, therefor almost certainly will trigger a cache miss (in CPU L1 cache) when accessing a single item list. So the cost will be x2 slow down at very least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibilities (in order of increasing memory foot print):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); // Concatenated string values
List<String> get(String key) {
    return Arrays.asList(map.getOrDefault(key, "").split("\f"));
}

Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
private static final String[] EMPTY = new String[0];
List<String> get(String key) {
    return Arrays.asList(map.getOrDefault(key, EMPTY));
}

Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>(); // LinkedList
List<String> get(String key) {
    return map.get(key);
}
```

(Just sample code. I did not deal well with empty strings.)

As said by others, **measure space and speed**. Also consider `Set<String>` as more optimal data structure instead of `List`. Consider `Collections.singletonList("...")` and `emptyList()`.

If strings are mostly Latin-1 consider java 9 uses more compact byte arrays (as opposed to java 8).

With large strings you could compress to `byte[]` using a `GZipOutputStream`.

And the final alternative, exhausting `java -Xmx` and physical memory: use a **database**.

Answer (score 2):

As others already suggested, you'll get a definite answer (for a given machine / JVM combination) only by measuring. But it's possible to predict at least some results.

Adding to Joop's suggestions, I can imagine a few different approaches:

- Use the straightforward `Map<String, List<String>>`, using `ArrayList` or a similar general-purpose List, then you get one additional (rather fat) wrapper object including a string array (maybe 128 bytes) per map entry. Implementation out-of-the-box, but wastes quite some memory.
- Use a `Map<String, List<String>>`, and make sure to wrap the single-string values in `Collections.singletonList()` or a similar compact construct. Then you get one additional wrapper object (16 to 32 bytes) per single string. Smaller overhead, but needs special treatment when inserting single strings.
- Use two maps, one `Map<String, String>` for the single strings and one `Map<String, List<String>>` for the multi-string case. Virtually no overhead, but needs special treatment both when inserting entries as well as when querying / iterating the map.
- Joop's concatenated-strings solution collapses two or more `String` instances into one longer `String`, thus eliminating their individual overheads. This even results in a "negative" overhead, but needs special treatment both when inserting entries as well as when querying / iterating the map. The `String` splitting will consume a tiny bit of extra runtime when retrieving entries, even for the single-string case. [Although `String.split()` is based on regular expressions, which are very slow in the general case,  Joop's solution matches a "fast path" in the `String.split()` implementation - kudos to Joop!]

Now, the choice is yours.